# goftp is throwing 502 error on every command

Tags: go, ftp

I'm trying to implement FTP client in golang. I'm using `goftp` library to do that. I'm able to login to the FTP server successfully, but after that every command (get the present working directory, upload a file etc) is throwing `panic: 502 Command  not implemented.` exception. For example, in the below code, I'm trying to get the present working directory after logging in to the server.

I'm able to do all kinds of operations through conventional ftp commands through CLI. But, here I'm blocked with `502` error code. Is there anything I'm missing here?

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"

    goftp "gopkg.in/dutchcoders/goftp.v1"
)

// Actual code
if ftp, err = goftp.Connect(host); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

defer ftp.Close()
fmt.Println("Successfully connected to", host)

if err = ftp.Login(username, password); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

pwd, err := ftp.Pwd()
if err == nil {
    fmt.Println("present working directory:", pwd)
} else {
    panic(err)
}
```

**EDIT**

After enabling debug mode (using `goftp.ConnectDbg(host)`), I got following log:

> 2019/10/25 22:26:03 < 220 Service ready for new user.
>
> 2019/10/25 22:26:03 220 Service ready for new user.
>
> 2019/10/25 22:26:03 > USER pkgajulapalli
>
> 2019/10/25 22:26:03 < 331 User name okay, need password for pkgajulapalli.
>
> 2019/10/25 22:26:03 > PASS password@123
>
> 2019/10/25 22:26:03 < 230 User logged in, proceed.
>
> Logged in with credentials
>
> 2019/10/25 22:26:05 > PWD
>
> 2019/10/25 22:26:05 < 502 Command  not implemented.
>
> panic: 502 Command  not implemented.

Comment: So maybe it is a problem that the specific server does not implement these commands. Does it work with some other FTP client?

Comment: Yes, I've mentioned it in the question. I'm able to perform these operations using ftp cli.

Comment: Works perfectly for me with [test.rebex.net](https://test.rebex.net/). Is the FTP server you are using publicly accessible?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, FTP server is not publicly accessible. It is from my local network. And I'm able to access it from the same machine using ftp cli.

Comment: Then please try your code against [test.rebex.net](https://test.rebex.net/). If it still does not work it is likely a problem with your code (you don't show everything) since it works for me. If it works though then it is likely a problem specific to your FTP server and cannot be reproduced and debugged without having access to it.

Comment: It worked with test.rebex.net. Not sure what is wrong with my FTP server.